# How i can to declare putStrLn or print in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, printing, declare

my answer is:

How can i declare print in function?

```
bisiesto :: Int -> **?**;
bisiesto x = if (x `mod` 4 == 0 && ((x `mod` 100 /= 0) || (x `mod` 400 == 0))) then  print("Es bisiesto") else print("No es bisiesto");
```

Please, who can i help me? Thanks.

Comment: bisiesto :: Int -> IO(); ok thanks for all i found it.

Comment: Check this out: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Leap_year#Haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version ( I changed the logic ):

```
bisiesto :: Int -> IO ()
bisiesto  n | even n = n : print "Es bisiesto"
            | otherwise = print "No es bisiesto"
```

Works like this:

```
Prelude> bisiesto 2
"Es bisiesto"
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) i'm noob in haskell sorry.

Comment: No problem, its a fun language, I'm just learning it as well.